# Google Script - Import images and list file names

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, upload

Maybe this is one of the impossible ones, but here goes.

I have a ton of images of qr-codes in a folder. It doesnt matter if its in google drive or in a local folder for me.

I would a script that automaticly loads all images in column A and then the file names in column B. AND automaticly adds new images when uploaded to the google drive folder.

Example: 
Qr1.jpeg will be loaded into cell a1 and cell b1 will be "Qr1"

Qr2.jpeg will be loaded into cell a2 and so on..

It would be nice if the images are scaled to 10x10 cm. :)

Is this even possible?

Hope you guys can help!

Thanks!

Oliver

Comment: I have tried searching for some different scripts to see if i can piece something together. But i have zero coding skills, and I havent been able to find anything remotely like this..

Comment: Well you could start by figuring out how to find and list all of the images in your folder first and then move on to figuring out how to insert one of them into a sheet. Take it step by step and when you run into problems come back here and share your code with us.

Comment: The only way this might be possible is to put a "watch" on a Google folder.  [Link to Apps Script documentation - watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch)  You can also do a web search using the words: "watch a folder in Google Drive"

Answer (score 0):

## Not the Complete Answer...but it's a part

I've been working on getting thumbnails into my spreadsheet ever since you asked this question.  I won't go into all the paths I took but I finally found this [Github link](https://gist.github.com/sjsyrek/de2c4b3506287cc87760) in the comments of [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36752396)

Which resulted in the following code:

```
function myImageFiles() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('MyImages');
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var s='';
  var cnt=1;
  while(files.hasNext()) 
  {
    var fi=files.next();
    var type=fi.getMimeType();

    if(type==MimeType.GIF || type==MimeType.JPEG || type==MimeType.PNG)
    {
      sh.appendRow([cnt++,fi.getName(),type,fi.getUrl(),'=IMAGE("' + getThumbNailLink(fi.getId()) + '",1)']);
    }
  } 
}

function getThumbNailLink(fileId)
{
  var file=Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  return file.thumbnailLink;
}
```

The result is now I have a spreadsheet with all of my image filenames and thumbnails.  You'll need Advanced Drive and take a close look at getThumbNailLink().